# Github action to checkout a sibling private repo fails on windows-2019 with ssh: Could not resolve hostname ....github.com: Name or service not known

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a github action to build a .NET Framework 4.8 solution on a windows-2019 github-hosted runner. The primary repo relies on a sibling repo (called Common.Net) that contains other projects needed to build. Getting the sibling repo fails with:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname key-blahblahblah.github.com: Name or service not known
Error: fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

The .yaml:

```
name: cd-build
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
      branches:
        - master
        - qa
        - dev
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-2019
    env:
      APP_NAME: RemoteSignWorkerDotNet
      
    steps:
      - name: Code Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3.5.0
    
      - name: Setup to use ssh instead of https
        run: git config --global url.git@github.com:.insteadOf https://github.com/

      - name: set key in ssh-agent
        uses: webfactory/ssh-agent@v0.7.0
        with:
          ssh-private-key: ${{ secrets.MYORG_COMMONDOTNET_PRIVATE_KEY }}

      - name: Code Checkout MyOrg/Common.Net
        uses: actions/checkout@v3.5.0
        with:
          repository: MyOrg/Common.Net
          token: ${{ secrets.MYORG_COMMONDOTNET_PRIVATE_KEY }}
          path: Common.Net
          ref: master
```

All of the steps succeed except for the last one named `Code Checkout MyOrg/Common.Net`, which gives the error noted above.

I know the Deploy keys are correct because when I change it from `runs-on: windows-2019` to `runs-on: ubuntu-latest` the above code checkout for Common.Net works just fine. This seems to be an issue with windows. How can I get this work on windows?

Comment: Is `MYORG_COMMONDOTNET_PRIVATE_KEY` a PAT or an SSH key?

Comment: @Azeem it's the SSH private key from the following cmd, run in gitbash on windows 10 ` ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "git@github.com:MyOrg/Common.Net.git`

Comment: Right. Then, shouldn't you be configuring [`ssh-key`](https://github.com/actions/checkout#usage) instead of `token`?

Comment: @Azeem That did the trick. Post it as an answer and I'll mark it accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your are using an SSH key and passing it as `token` where a PAT should go. It should be configured via `ssh-key`.

Please refer to the [usage of `actions/checkout`](https://github.com/actions/checkout#usage):

```
# Personal access token (PAT) used to fetch the repository. The PAT is configured
# with the local git config, which enables your scripts to run authenticated git
# commands. The post-job step removes the PAT.
# ...
#
# Default: ${{ github.token }}
token: ''
```

and,

```
# SSH key used to fetch the repository. The SSH key is configured with the local
# git config, which enables your scripts to run authenticated git commands. The
# post-job step removes the SSH key.
# ...
ssh-key: ''
```